# Setting a textfield in actionscript to "0" causes it to be blank

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have the following code that loads an XML file, parses it, and then sets various text fields to the contents of the XML file:

```
function loadData(): void {
var myXML: XML;
var myLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SplitmediaLabs\\XSplit\\streamcontrol.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

    function processXML(e: Event): void {
        myXML = new XML(e.target.data);

        alliance1Score.text = myXML.elements("alliance1Score"); 
        alliance2Score.text = myXML.elements("alliance2Score");
    }
}
```

The XML file is set up as such:

```
<alliance1Score><![CDATA[2]]></alliance1Score>
<alliance2Score><![CDATA[0]]></alliance2Score>
```

When the value is 2 or 1 this works great and the textfields change.  When the value is 0, however, the textfields are blank.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why the CDATA when storing numbers?

Comment: No reason.  Problem still occurs without CDATA, though.

Comment: Works for me:  `var xml:XML = <node><alliance1Score><![CDATA[0]]></alliance1Score></node>

trace(xml..alliance1Score[0]);`

Comment: xml nodes are not String, they are parsed to string if possible and not parsed at all if not possible. 0 evaluates to null so nothing is added, fix it by casting to String: String(myXML.elements("alliance2Score"))

Comment: Is there more to your xml than what you've posted?  They need a root element to work properly

Comment: @BotMastr - 0 does not evaluate to null

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a problem with embedding my font.  I had accidentally missed checking "Numerals".

Comment: @LDMS If 1 and 2 appeared elsewhere in a Textfield with the same font as part of the default value, they would be embedded too.

Comment: @hanenbro - I think we are saying the same thing?   If it was a font embedding issue, 0 should have same result as 1 or 2 or any other numeral?  Or are you saying FLASH IDE auto embeds specific glyphs if used in a design time text field?

Comment: @LDMS That's right, it's specific to the Flash IDE (which I guess only became implied with the mention of the Numerals checkbox, above). But yeah, it will embed any glyphs used with a particular font as if they'd been added to the 'Also include these characters' field in the Font Embedding window, so - confusingly - you can end up with partially embedded character groups.